# Task scheduling using acceptEither synchronously on CompletableFuture

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future, completion-stage

I am learning concurrency through the CompletableFuture API. Let's say I have two tasks: one takes 250ms and another takes 2500ms. In the following code:

```
        Supplier<List<Long>> supplyIds = () -> {
            sleep(200);
            return(Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L));
        };

        Function<List<Long>, CompletableFuture<List<User>>> fetchUsers1 = idList -> {
            sleep(250);
            System.out.println("User2"+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Supplier<List<User>> userSupplier = () ->  idList.stream().map(User::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
            return(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(userSupplier));
        };
        Function<List<Long>, CompletableFuture<List<User>>> fetchUsers2 = idList -> {
            sleep(2500);
            System.out.println("User2"+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Supplier<List<User>> userSupplier = () -> idList.stream().map(User::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
            return(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(userSupplier));
        };
        Consumer<List<User>> displayer = users -> {
            users.forEach(System.out::println);
        };

        CompletableFuture<List<Long>> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplyIds);
        CompletableFuture<List<User>> users1 = completableFuture.thenCompose(fetchUsers1);
        CompletableFuture<List<User>> users2 = completableFuture.thenCompose(fetchUsers2);

        users1.thenRun(()-> System.out.println("User 1"));
        users2.thenRun(()-> System.out.println("User 2"));
        users1.acceptEither(users2, displayer);

        sleep(6000);
```

I get the following result:

```
User2ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
User 2
1
2
3
User2ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
User 1
```

I understand that the code is running synchronously since the same common fork join pool thread is being used and we don't specify the thread. I am confused as to why the `fetchUsers2`task is being executed first and then `fetchUsers1`task (this seems to be consistent with each run). I assumed that since `thenCompose` is called on `fetchUsers1` first in the code, it would be 'queued up' first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in the documentation says that the order of invocation matters for `thenCompose`.

Since you define two *independent* stages, both only depending on `completableFuture`, there is no defined order between `users1` and `user2` and the resulting order is just implementation dependent.

You may reproducibly get a particular order in one environment, but a different order in a different environment. Even in your environment, it’s possible to get a different order in some runs. If the initiating thread loses the CPU after calling `supplyAsync(supplyIds)` for 200 milliseconds, it might execute the action specified with `thenCompose(fetchUsers1)` immediately at the invocation, before the invocation of `thenCompose(fetchUsers2)`.

When the order between two actions matters, you must model a dependency between them.

Note that likewise the code

```
users1.thenRun(()-> System.out.println("User 1"));
users2.thenRun(()-> System.out.println("User 2"));
users1.acceptEither(users2, displayer);
```

defines entirely independent actions. Since `acceptEither` is applied to `users1` and `users2`, rather than the completion stages returned by the `thenRun` calls, it is not dependent on the completion of the print statements. These three actions may be performed in any order.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer. Could you elaborate more on what you mean by the order being implementation-dependant?